# How to set focus on child of content editable HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I've been trying to create an advanced text input where users can write hashtags.
The input is a div with contenteditable set true, and the hashtags should be child nodes as I'd allow users to put space inside the hashtags.

My problem is that on some browsers I can not set the focus on the hashtag's child node as the user types. On Chrome/Linux and Safari/OSX it seems to work well, but on Firefox and Chrome/OSX setting the focus don't seem to work. (I haven't got to Windows yet.)

```
var $elComposer = $('#composer');

var InsertTagPair = function (tagtype) {
    var newTag = document.createElement (tagtype);
    $(newTag).attr ('contenteditable', 'true');
    $(newTag).attr ('class', 'tag');
    $elComposer.off ('keypress');
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.getRangeAt && selection.rangeCount) {
            var range = selection.getRangeAt (0);
            range.deleteContents ();
            range.insertNode (newTag);
            range.selectNodeContents (newTag);
            range.collapse (false);
            selection.removeAllRanges ();
            selection.addRange (range);
        };
    };
    newTag.focus ();
    return newTag;
};

var ComposerOnKeyPressed = function (event) {
    if (event.charCode == 35) { // #
        var contextTag = InsertTagPair ('span');
        $elComposer.attr ('contenteditable', 'false');
        return false;
    };
    return event;
};
$elComposer.on ('keypress', ComposerOnKeyPressed);
```

The above code is the essential part that's not working. See it here in action:

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cja963ym/1/

To see a more complete version of the composer that makes more sense see this instead:

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g_borgulya/ur6zk32s/15/

Symptom: on Firefox if you type in the editable div and press '#', you manually have to click it by mouse or move the focus with tab to be able to edit the hashtag, while on other platforms it gets the focus when I call `newTag.focus()` on the element.

I don't know how to move on, even how to debug this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding `newTag.focus()` in the "#" handler made it work in Chrome and Firefox (Win) (it didn't before, but did on IE11, just wanted to let you know)

Fiddle fork : http://jsfiddle.net/ekxo4ra3/

Does that look OK for what you wanted ?

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect. Although I don't understand why/how your solution is working if the other isn't. It seems to me that you can change focus only after the parent `contenteditable` is set to `false`. Does this makes sense somehow?

Comment: From what I've tested, making the container not `contenteditable` anymore simply makes children elements lose the focus... _at least in some browsers_. Anyway, that probably explains why setting the focus before makes it useless as it gets removed right after.

Comment: Good to know this. I spent hours with this problem. Thanks!